# NSUserDefaults and adding void* data in it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have data in format

```
struct CardData
{
   void* frontimagedata;
}
```

I need to hold this data in `NSUserDefaults` [ Need to use this data after app launch again after exit]. I am not using database in my app.

I need to use this format only as this CardData information is shared between Obj c and c++ code.

can anyone help me on this.

thanks,

Sagar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save it into an `NSData` object you'll be able to store it in `NSUserDefaults`.

```
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes:frontimagedata length:datalen];
```